# Custom circular progressbar in Qt

Tags: qt, qpainter, qt5.6

I'm able to do circular progressbar in  qt while overriding `paintEvent` of the widget and draw circular progressbar but having a difficulty with the second circular progressbar (not able to draw like this) behind main circular progressbar:

[image]

Can anybody guide me through? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see what's the problem here, you can use `QPainterPath` and adding a full or partial arc path to it, then draw the path via `QPen` using a `Qt::DotLine` style.

If the stock dotted line doesn't work for you, there is the option to [specify a custom pattern](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpen.html#setDashPattern) via:

```
void QPen::setDashPattern(const QVector<qreal> & pattern)
```

---

Here is a quick example, looking like this:

[image]

```
class CPBar : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    qreal p; // progress 0.0 to 1.0
  public:
    CPBar(QWidget * p = 0) : QWidget(p), p(0) {
      setMinimumSize(208, 208);
    }
    void upd(qreal pp) {
      if (p == pp) return;
      p = pp;
      update();
    }
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
    qreal pd = p * 360;
    qreal rd = 360 - pd;
    QPainter p(this);
    p.fillRect(rect(), Qt::white);
    p.translate(4, 4);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    QPainterPath path, path2;
    path.moveTo(100, 0);
    path.arcTo(QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200), 90, -pd);
    QPen pen, pen2;
    pen.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
    pen.setColor(QColor("#30b7e0"));
    pen.setWidth(8);
    p.strokePath(path, pen);
    path2.moveTo(100, 0);
    pen2.setWidth(8);
    pen2.setColor(QColor("#d7d7d7"));
    pen2.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
    pen2.setDashPattern(QVector<qreal>{0.5, 1.105});
    path2.arcTo(QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200), 90, rd);
    pen2.setDashOffset(2.2);
    p.strokePath(path2, pen2);
  }  
};

class Test : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Test() {
      QVBoxLayout * l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
      CPBar * p = new CPBar;
      QSlider * s = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
      s->setMinimum(0);
      s->setMaximum(100);
      l->addWidget(p);
      l->addWidget(s);
      setLayout(l);
      connect(s, &QSlider::valueChanged, [=](){ p->upd((qreal)s->value() / s->maximum());});
    }
};
```