# Circular Progress Bar with PySide6, python3

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, progress-bar, cross-platform, pyside6

I was wondering how to create a circular progress bar with PySide6. Currently i already found the solution and will post it here hoping that this can help someone.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the solution for PySide6 based on [@dtech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991484/dtech)'s answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793906/custom-circular-progressbar-in-qt/42794690#42794690):

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QSlider, QWidget, QApplication


class CPBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.p=0
        self.setMinimumSize(208, 208)

    def upd(self,pp):
        if self.p == pp:
            return
        self.p = pp
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self,e):
        pd = self.p * 360
        rd = 360 - pd
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.fillRect(self.rect(), Qt.white)
        p.translate(4, 4)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        path, path2 = QPainterPath(),QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(100, 0)
        path.arcTo(QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200), 90, -pd)
        pen, pen2 = QPen(), QPen()
        pen.setCapStyle(Qt.FlatCap)
        pen.setColor(QColor("#30b7e0"))
        pen.setWidth(8)
        p.strokePath(path, pen)
        path2.moveTo(100, 0)
        pen2.setWidth(8)
        pen2.setColor(QColor("#d7d7d7"))
        pen2.setCapStyle(Qt.FlatCap)
        pen2.setDashPattern([0.5, 1.105]) # remove this line to have continue cercle line
        path2.arcTo(QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200), 90, rd)
        pen2.setDashOffset(2.2) # this one too
        p.strokePath(path2, pen2)


class Test(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      l = QVBoxLayout(self)
      p = CPBar()
      s = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
      s.setMinimum(0)
      s.setMaximum(100)
      l.addWidget(p)
      l.addWidget(s)
      self.setLayout(l)
      s.valueChanged.connect(lambda :p.upd(s.value()/s.maximum()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    main_widget = Test()
    main_widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Result:

[image: Pyside 6 circular progress bar]

I readaptated it to have a version with progress text in the middle of the circle, a transparent background and a more responsive widget:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QColor, QBrush, QFont
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QSlider, QWidget, QApplication


class CPBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.p = 0
        self.setMinimumSize(50, 50)

    def upd(self, pp):
        if self.p == pp:
            return
        self.p = pp
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.height() > self.width():
            self.setFixedWidth(self.height())
        if self.width() > self.height():
            self.setFixedHeight(self.width())
        pd = self.p * 360
        rd = 360 - pd
        p = QPainter(self)
        # p.fillRect(self.rect(), Qt.white)
        p.translate(4, 4)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        path, path2 = QPainterPath(), QPainterPath()
        circle_width = self.width() - self.width() / 10
        widht_half = circle_width/2
        path.moveTo(widht_half, 0)
        circle_rect = QRectF(self.rect().left() / 2, self.rect().top() / 2, circle_width, self.height() - self.height() / 10)
        path.arcTo(circle_rect, 90, -pd)
        pen, pen2 = QPen(), QPen()
        pen.setCapStyle(Qt.FlatCap)
        pen.setColor(QColor("#30b7e0"))
        pen_width = self.width()/25
        pen.setWidth(pen_width)
        p.strokePath(path, pen)
        path2.moveTo(widht_half, 0)
        pen2.setWidth(pen_width)
        pen2.setColor(QColor("#d7d7d7"))
        pen2.setCapStyle(Qt.FlatCap)
        pen2.setDashPattern([0.5, 1.105]) # remove this line to have continue cercle line
        path2.arcTo(circle_rect, 90, rd)
        pen2.setDashOffset(2.2) # this one too
        p.strokePath(path2, pen2)

        p.setPen(pen)
        font = QFont()
        percent_size = self.height() / 7
        font.setPointSizeF(percent_size)
        p.setFont(font)
        percent_text_position = self.rect().center()
        p_in_percent = self.p * 100
        percent_text_position.setX(percent_text_position.x() - (
                percent_size + (self.width()/6 if p_in_percent >= 100 else self.width()/10 if p_in_percent >= 10 else +self.width()/40)))
        percent_text_position.setY(percent_text_position.y() + percent_size * 2 / 5)
        p.drawText(percent_text_position, f"{round(self.p * 100, 0)}%")


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        l = QVBoxLayout(self)
        p = CPBar(self)
        s = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        s.setMinimum(0)
        s.setMaximum(100)
        l.addWidget(p)
        l.addWidget(s)
        self.setLayout(l)
        s.valueChanged.connect(lambda: p.upd(s.value() / s.maximum()))
        # connect(s, &QSlider::valueChanged, [=](){ p->upd((qreal)s->value() / s->maximum());});


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    main_widget = Test()
    main_widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Result:

[image: Pyside 6 circular progress bar with progress text]